# multiple foreach loop with mysql join

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure my database design and coding structure is efficient or not to fetch expected result.

For example, I have to fetch student `smith` details, his general information and his obtained marks in **each term** in **each subject** with **each category**.

Following is my database structure

**Student**

```
id  |   Roll    |   name    |   class
=====================================
1   |   1       |   smith   |   7
```

**Subject**

```
id  |   title
=============
1   |   Science
2   |   Math
```

**Exam**

```
id  |   title
=================
1   |   First Term 
2   |   Second Term
```

**Marks**

```
id  |   std_id  |   sub_id  |   th  |   pr  |   exm_id
======================================================
1   |   1       |   1       |   60  |   20  |   1
2   |   1       |   2       |   55  |   18  |   1
3   |   1       |   1       |   70  |   23  |   2
4   |   1       |   2       |   61  |   19  |   2
```

Now I am trying to fetch result as

```
Name : Smith
class:  7
Progress Report
    First Term
        Science
            Th:60 | PR:20
        Math
            Th:55 | PR:18

    Second Term
        Science
            Th:70 | PR:23
        Math
            Th:61 | PR:19
```

But, following is output what I am getting, I can't fetch result as exam-wise, so all exam share all marks each other

```
Name : Smith
class:  7
Progress Report
    First Term
        Science
            Th:60 | PR:20
        Math
            Th:55 | PR:18
        Science
            Th:70 | PR:23
        Math
            Th:61 | PR:19

    Second Term
        Science
            Th:60 | PR:20
        Math
            Th:55 | PR:18
        Science
            Th:70 | PR:23
        Math
            Th:61 | PR:19
```

I've tried `group.by` to `exam.id`, though it fetch result exam-wise which is expecting result, but it repeats same student

```
Name : Smith
class:  7
Progress Report
    First Term
        Science
            Th:60 | PR:20
        Math
            Th:55 | PR:18

Name : Smith
class:  7
Progress Report
    Second Term
        Science
            Th:70 | PR:23
        Math
            Th:61 | PR:19
```

Here is **Mysql and PHP code**

```
$result=$con->prepare(
    "SELECT
        student.id, student.rid, student.name AS name, student.class,

        class.title AS class, 

        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT exam.title) AS exam,
        GROUP_CONCAT(subject.title, '<br/> Th - ', mark.th, ' | PR - ', mark.pr SEPARATOR ',') AS mark

        FROM student
        JOIN class ON class.id = student.class 
        JOIN mark ON mark.std_id = student.id
        JOIN exam ON exam.id = mark.exm_id
        JOIN subject ON subject.id = mark.sub_id

        WHERE student.id=:id
        GROUP BY student.id;" //If exam.id is added here, it works but repeats student
) or die($con->error);

$result->bindParam(':id',$_POST['std']);
$result->execute();
while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $name=$row['name'];
    $class=$row['class'];
    $exm_array = explode(',',$row['exam']);
    $mrk_array = explode(',',$row['mark']); 
    echo "
    Name: $name<br/>
    Class: $class<br/>
    Progress Report<br/>";

    // I think there are other fine alternative way instead of foreach

    foreach(array_values($exm_array) as $i => $exam){
        echo "<span class='col100'>".$exam."<br/>Mark:</span>";
        foreach(array_values($mrk_array) as $i => $mark){
            echo "<span class='col100'> ".$mark."</span>";
        }
    }
}
```

Raw output
[image]

Comment: Can you show the output of the query, before you start doing anything to it with PHP?

Comment: @Moseleyi, you mean the output without `foreach loop`

Comment: Yes, just a raw SQL output for, let's say, one user

Comment: @Moseleyi, I am not sure, what you mean, but I've edited post, added snapshot while running query in mysql, Please check it once

Comment: So your problem is the fact that a person has two same exams? Like Smith has two sets of marks for a Science exam in First term. Is it correct or you just want to select one? If latter, which one?

Comment: @Moseleyi, Let me clarify, yes `smith` has two sets of `exams`. `First-Term`, `Second-Term`, each `Term`, same `subjects` are there, but only `Marks` will be different. So I want to show `Smith's` term-wise `mark`. Smith has different `marks` in different `term` for same `subject`

Comment: Okay I see what you're trying to do.. now my question is why are you trying to do such complicated thing in SQL. You still need to loop through it so why `GROUP_CONCAT` if you're "exploding" it. You might as well return a nice associative array and then deal with displaying it there. The query is fine and works as it should..

Comment: @Moseleyi, Great tips, I found other answers also convey message do not priority `GROUP_CONTACT`, instead of this, how can I do, can you give some hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my best guess how to implement it.

1. Load marks into PHP array
2. Loop through students with modified query (only one `GROUP_CONCAT()`)
3. Display the name of the student
4. Get the right array of terms for student it from preloaded data
5. Loop through the array to display each term

First query, load all marks:

```
SELECT
    student.id,
    exam.title AS exam,
    GROUP_CONCAT(subject.title, '<br/> Th - ', mark.th, ' | PR - ', mark.pr SEPARATOR ',') AS mark
FROM student
    JOIN mark ON mark.std_id = student.id
    JOIN exam ON exam.id = mark.exm_id
    JOIN subject ON subject.id = mark.sub_id
GROUP BY
    student.id,
    exam.title
```

And store it in PHP array like you have `$marks_array`

Then loop through students:

```
SELECT
    student.id,
    student.rid,
    student.name AS 'name',
    student.class,
    class.title AS 'class_title'
FROM student
    JOIN class ON class.id = student.class
```

And inside the loop call the right records to loop again:

`$marks_array[<student_id>]` - this would be an array that has two values (one for each exam)

Have a try and let me know if it makes sense..

Comment: @Moselyi, Thanks Man !!, this way works, but as your suggestion in comment, I found I was doing wrong using huge `GROUP_CONCAT` and making complicated query, So I ignore `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP BY`, and switch to `while loop` and `if condition` with `join`, I hadn't thought this way query would be faster and optimized